# tools.jar missing when trying to install android studio on linux debian crunchbang

Tags: java, android, linux, debian

I get the following error when i try to run ./studio.sh from command line:

'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

And here are the paths, which appear to be correct to me:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdkg

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're incorrect.

You need the Standard Edition Oracle JDK, not the OpenJDK

Also, you need JDK 6, not 7 (yes, 7 is backward-compatible, and it's been reported to work for Android, but the official android documentation only says that it supports 5 or 6)

And yes, it does seem like you have 1.6 and 1.7 installed (I just noticed that after you made your edit), but you seem to be confused about which one you should be using in your environment variables.

Comment: Hi Stephan?? are you there